# Color from imported OBJ not displayed in Blender

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, objects, import, point-clouds

I want to import some .obj file that I have made with MeshLab. The point cloud file was actually in .pcd format and I used pcl_pcd2ply tools from PCL to change it into PLY-Format. Then I import it into Meshlab and make the mesh out of it. I used the texture and texture color as the object color. At the end, I have some file in MTL, PNG(for texture color) and the OBJ-Formats.

When I drag the OBJ file in Meshlab it shows the mesh with some color (before in point cloud just some random points). Then I tried to import the OBJ into Blender I could only see the mesh without the color. How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you looking at it? By default the viewport is in *solid view* which doesn't display textures (at least, not be default). Try rendering it or switching to textured view (Alt Z)

Comment: @gandalf3 Thank you very much. That solves my problem completely.